# How to throttle a spring remote batch slave

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

We are in the process of converting a number of batch jobs chunked batch to remote chunked batch, because we need to be able to process up to 1 million chunks in a defined timeframe. We have the jobs running but we have some issues related to performance.

Our job has rather long processing times per entry/chunk, usually a few seconds.

We use the following configuration on the slave side:

```
<bean id="ourTaskExecutor" class="...ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="16" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="16" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="256" />
</bean>

<int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="JobJmsRequests" 
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    channel="requests.chunking" 
    destination-name="requests.chunking" >
        <int:poller task-executor="ourTaskExecutor" 
            fixed-delay="50" 
            max-messages-per-poll="4" 
            receive-timeout="50"/>
</int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
    id="JobJmsReplies" 
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" 
    destination-name="replies.chunking" 
    channel="replies.chunking"/>

<int:service-activator 
    id="JobActivator" 
    input-channel="requests.chunking" 
    output-channel="replies.chunking" 
    ref="JobChunkHandler" method="handleChunk"/>
```

We have set the master node to throttle on 64 chunks, so no more than 64 chunks should be being processed at any time.

Our assumption was that the poller would hand over the received messages to task executor for them to be processed, but then no more than 64 messages could end up in the task executor, which has room for 256+16 messages.

However, we are seeing exceptions that the queue capacity has been reached and tasks are rejected by the task executor. We think this is because the task executor is used only by the poller and processing the obtained requests on the polling thread. Since processing takes long, we slowly flood the task executor with polling tasks. and processing everything they receive in a single thread).

We cannot explain the flooding entirely, since we use a receivetimeout and a delay, so our understanding is that processing should be done before a new poll would be triggered. This however seems not the case.

What we basically are trying to configure is the following:

Only 16 messages should be processed concurrently. Addtional messages would be queued (using a rather small queue, say about the size of the pool). 
When the pool is full, we would like the poller to get blocked until room is available in the thread pool again. We do not want a slave to eagerly fetch too much work.

We would like to have polling and execution of messages on different threads. Is that possible and how can that be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a caller-runs or caller-blocks `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

That said, you don't want in-memory chunks - they will be lost on a system failure.

You should use a message-driven inbound channel adapter with the concurrency set to the number of concurrent chunks that you want to process.